# Is there an MPPT charger to charge a 540 V battery with a 200-300 V PV panel?

Tags: solar-charge-controller

I am planning to design an EV boat. I have a PV panel of about 200-300 V and a 540 V LiFePo4 battery.

My question is: How can I charge my battery with the PV panel if there is no MPPT that can boost to the high voltage for charging?

Comment: H nocab. I am not really super clear on what you are asking. If there is no boost-mode solar charge controller that can do what you want, I guess you will have to design and make one. It sounds like a very specialized product, so I would not be surprised if it does not exist.

Comment: Commercially available MPPT solar chargers that can boost voltage are uncommon, but they do exist. I have never seen one that will work at the voltages you mention, though.

Comment: So a possibility is to change the panel configuration to give 550V or so…

Comment: Boosting voltage to a higher level is certainly possible, there are customized/not so common MPPT converters that use a buck-boost converter to achieve higher voltages. However they come with their own issues and boost converters under no load need special protections to avoid very high voltages/damaged transistors. Can you reduce the battery voltage by changing the configuration?

Comment: These are NOT directly what you want, but these suppliers may know of sources. [PV to 540V MPPT](https://cnbangzhao.en.alibaba.com/product/62313432521-803635198/480V_540V_600V_DC_Lithium_Battery_bank_Charge_controller_from_PV_modules_PWM_or_MPPT_type_.html) - probably only buck conversion.

Comment: [Similar](https://www.stinenergypv.com/mppt-solar-charge-controller-192v-540v_p29.html)